# Inserting Data From Perl To MysQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I have already connected MySQL to the database but the problem is that 
I have some problems with inserting Data from Perl to Mysql.

The error that pops out is:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./etl_server_info.pl line 204, (Which is the connection of the database ) 

DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed at ($stmt->execute($sql);)
```

```
sub insert_record(){

 my($data,$db_config)=@_;
 my $result = -1; # -1 fail;  0 - succ

  # connect to db
  # connect to MySQL database
  my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=".$db_config->{'Top_Data'}.";host=".$db_config->{'127.0.0.1'}.";port=".$db_config->{'3306'};
my $username = $db_config->{'username'};
my $password = $db_config->{'password'};

my %attr = (PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr) or die $DBI::errstr;

print "We Have Successfully Connected To The Database \n";

  # prepare sql statement
  # execute insert
  my $sql = 'insert into Top(Load_Average, CPU_us, CPU_id, CPU-wa, CPU_hi, CPU_si, CPU_st, Swap_Total, Swap_Free, Swap_Used, Memory_Total, Memeory_Free, Memory_Used, Memory_Buff, Date) values(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,date)';




  my $stmt =$dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Its A Fail" . $dbh->errstr();
  $stmt->execute($sql);



  $stmt->finish();
  $dbh->disconnect();
  $result = 0;
  return($result);
```

Comment: `insert into sometable (foo, bar, baz) values ( ?, ?, ?)` and then
    
`$stmt->execute( $foo, $bar, $baz)`

Comment: that doest work for me :U

Comment: Read `perldoc DBI`. Your code is wrong. You must pass exact values to execute() and use placeholders in statement as I told. You pass statement to execute(), this is mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `$db_config` variable looks suspicious to me. Either your config hash is strange, or you're using values instead of keys.

You haven't shown us where `$db_config` is set up, but I'd guess it looks something like this:

```
$db_config = {
  name => 'Top_Data',
  host => '127.0.0.1',
  port => 3306,
  username => 'someone',
  password => 'a secret',
};
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=".$db_config->{name}.";host=".$db_config->{host}.";port=".$db_config->{port};
```

Notice that I've used the key names (`name`, `host` and `port`) instead of the values (`Top_Data`, `127.0.0.1` and `3306`).

I'll also point out that you can simplify this slightly by using Perl's ability to expand variables inside a double-quoted string.

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$db_config->{name};host=$db_config->{host};port=$db_config->{port}";
```

There's another problem later on, with your SQL statement.

```
my $sql = 'insert into Top(Load_Average, CPU_us, CPU_id, CPU-wa, CPU_hi, 
           CPU_si, CPU_st, Swap_Total, Swap_Free, Swap_Used, Memory_Total, 
           Memeory_Free, Memory_Used, Memory_Buff, Date) 
           values(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,
           varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,date)';
```

The values that you should be inserting are the actual data items. So where you have the strings "float", "varchar" or "date", you should actually have data items (a floating-point number, a string or a date).

Finally, having prepared your statement, you don't need to pass it to the `execute()` method. You should, however, look at using bind points in your SQL and passing your actual data items to the `execute()` call

Comment: But how can i put multiple items in one coloum if my data is an array ...

so do i change the value into this (?) ..... since the data is many and not a single data ?

Comment: @DreamMember: You prepare your statement once (`my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)`) with `?` in place of the actual values. Then you loop over your data and call `$sth->execute(@data)` for each iteration of the loop - with `@data` containing one row of data items each time.